# Angular ui routing navigate with parameters

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-ui-router, console.log

In `html` I have two buttons **Users** and **Surveys** -

```
<button *ngIf="isUserAdmin" mat-button (click)="listSurveys()">Survey</button>
<button *ngIf="isUserAdmin" mat-button (click)="list('users')">Users</button>
```

And in `.ts` file, I've two methods for navigating to the corresponding list pages -

```
 listSurveys(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['surveys']);
  };

  listUsers(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['users']);
  };
```

The above setup works as expected. But I just want to replace the **`listUsers()/listSurveys()`** with **`list(items: String)`** method like this

**.HTML:**

```
<button *ngIf="isUserAdmin" mat-button (click)="list('surveys')">Survey</button>
<button *ngIf="isUserAdmin" mat-button (click)="list('users')">Users</button>
```

**.TS:**

```
list(items : String) {
    console.log("\'" +items+ "\'");
    this.router.navigate(["\'" +items+ "\'"]);
  }
```

But this is not working, though `the console.log()` logs - 'surveys' and 'users' in respectively in the console. Can anyone help on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just do `this.router.navigate([items]);`. You're adding unwanted quotes.

Comment: @Jeto thanks a lot it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button *ngIf="isUserAdmin" mat-button (click)="list('surveys')">Survey</button>
<button *ngIf="isUserAdmin" mat-button (click)="list('user')">User</button>
```

**TS**

```
list(param:string): void {
    this.router.navigate([ param ]);
  };
```

**For more detail**
https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 2):

i think this will work

```
list(items : String) {
    console.log(items);
    this.router.navigate([items]);
  }
```